# Uploading cakePHP through cpanel issues

Tags: cakephp

i'm using cakephp version 2.3.6, ive been trying to upload cake to a hostgator server through CPanel but been having problems configuring the index.php file in the webroot but not sure the correct configuration for my version of cake on Cpanel my cpanel username is fredenda I tried to configure this in cpanel but keeps on giving this error message

" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/fredenda/public_html/index.php on line 41"

however this error isnt in the file, Please can someone help me out.
Please check the file below... bless.

```
<?php
/**
 * Index
 *
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc.      
(http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.webroot
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
 if (!defined('DS')) {
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

/**
* These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in
* a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.
 * When using custom settings be sure to use the DS and do not add a trailing DS.
*/

/**
* The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.(fredenda);
}

/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
}

/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 * Un-comment this line to specify a fixed path to CakePHP.
* This should point at the directory containing `Cake`.
 *
 * For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path. If you
 * cannot modify your include_path set this value.
  *
* Leaving this constant undefined will result in it being defined in Cake/bootstrap.php
 *
* The following line differs from its sibling
 * /lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/webroot/index.php
 */

 define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib')

/**
 * Editing below this line should NOT be necessary.
  * Change at your own risk.
  *
  */
 if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
 }
 if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
 }

// for built-in server
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/' && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    return false;
   }
   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);
   }

    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
    ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR .         ini_get('include_path'));
}
if (!include ('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
    $failed = true;
}
 } else {
if (!include (CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
    $failed = true;
}
 }
```

if (!empty($failed)) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of     CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory    containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}

```
  App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

 $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
 $Dispatcher->dispatch(
new CakeRequest(),
new CakeResponse()
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your eyes. ;) The parser is not lying to you. There is a missing ) but I don't think fredenda is a constant so...

```
define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.(fredenda);
```

This line should be:

```
define('ROOT', DS . 'home' . DS. 'fredenda');
```

I would recommend you to get an editor or IDE with proper php syntax highlighting and syntax check to see these kind of syntax issues immediately.

And follow [coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html), there should be a space between the DS and strings like in all the other places. Also a good read this book "[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)".

Comment: ok thanks for that, however i need to know the correct configuration for cake 2.3 on a hostgator server through cpanel thanks.